# MVVM: customize devexpress propertyGridControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

I have a PropertyGridControl in my XAML. It shows the properties of an object, from the selected row of a GridControl. When I click a row, it populates the PropertyGridControl. I'm working with the MVVM pattern.

The XAML of the propertyGridControl is:

```
<dxprg:PropertyGridControl  SelectedObject="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=lst1}" ShowProperties="All" ShowCategories="False" Margin="473,0,0,133"/>
```

But how can I customize the PropertyGridControl? 
EXAMPLE:

from this:

[image]

to this:
[image]

The focus point, for me, is customize the boolean/tinyint fields of the database in radio button element and the external key in a combobox.

FOR DMITRIG:

following yout hint, now I have my xaml file, with:

```
<dxlc:DataLayoutControl Grid.Column="1" CurrentItem="{Binding GroupedLayoutData}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="204" Margin="10,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278"/>
```

and my viewModel.cs file, where I created a UI following the sample. But I can't see nothing, where is the mistake?

```
   public class GroupedLayoutData {
        const string JobGroup = "Job";
        const string ContactGroup = "Contact";
        const string AddressGroup = "Address";
        const string PersonalGroup = "Personal";

        [Display(GroupName = AddressGroup, ShortName = "", Order = 4)]
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        [Display(GroupName = AddressGroup, ShortName = "")]
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        [Display(GroupName = PersonalGroup, Name = "Birth date")]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        [Display(GroupName = ContactGroup)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First name", Order = 0)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(GroupName = PersonalGroup, Order = 5)]
        //public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        //[Display(GroupName = JobGroup, Order = 2)]
        public string Group { get; set; }
        [Display(GroupName = JobGroup, Name = "Hire date")]
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last name", Order = 1)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(GroupName = ContactGroup, Order = 3), DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Display(GroupName = JobGroup), DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        [Display(GroupName = JobGroup, Order = 21)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT ii: How do I bind the class defining my layout to my datalayoutcontrol?

Comment: Are all the properties known to you?

Comment: looks to me like a `TemplateSelector` job. [Here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector) is a link to get you started. It helped me to understand how to approach similar problem.

Comment: @bit: yes, I know all the properties. The data are records from my db.

Comment: @XAMIMAX: now I'm looking... I hope it's another simply but useful hint! :)

Comment: @XAMlMAX I read it... but... is it work also for devexpress object? I've tried it and I think not.. or am I wrong? Did you ever used it for devexpress objects? Do you have an example?

Comment: No I haven't used the DevExpress but if you have a `TemplateSelector` property on your UI element than you can use it. And yes I have used `TemplateSelector` on a `ComboBoxItems`. Well I can't tell if you're doing it wrong until you show us some code. Update your question with your attempt and we'll take it from there.

Comment: then why don't you create the required UI instead of using a PropertyGrid?

Comment: @bit because I'm using the MVVM pattern and I cannot write specific properties from the model/view model in the view.

Comment: @bit i was reading again my last comment... well, I'm a newbie, so give me a hint, if you know... what do you mean with building a UI? a user control? and this is suitable for mvvm pattern?

Comment: Since you want some properties grouped, and remaining listed in Textblock (name) => Textbox (value) pairs. You should define a new class (UI) enlisting the grouped properties and other properties. And then should use an ItemsControl to bind them in the View.

Comment: @bit where can I find an example of custom UI?

Comment: Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the DevExpress for accomplishing a task that you described, I suggest you to try using the [DataLayoutControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11540). This control will automatically build a layout to edit object's public properties when you bind a DataLayoutControl to any data-object via the [DataLayoutControl.CurrentItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfLayoutControlDataLayoutControl_CurrentItemtopic) property.

Below the minimal example with DataLayoutControl and Grid:

Model(C# code):

```
public class Person {
    const string PersonalGroup = "Personal";
    [Display(Name = "First Name", GroupName = PersonalGroup)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name", GroupName = PersonalGroup)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Birth date", GroupName = PersonalGroup)]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    [Display(GroupName = PersonalGroup)]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Display(GroupName = "Contact"), DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel(C# code)

```
public class ViewModel {
    public ViewModel() {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person> { 
            new Person(){ FirstName = "Peter", LastName ="Parker", Age=33 },
            new Person(){ FirstName = "Mary", LastName ="Jane" , Age=31 }
        };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; private set; }
    public Person SelectedPerson { get; set; }
}
```

View (XAML-markup):

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <dxg:GridControl Grid.Column="0" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
        >
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView ShowGroupPanel="False" BestFitArea="All" AllowEditing="False"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
    <dxlc:DataLayoutControl Grid.Column="1"
            CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
       />
</Grid>
```

Result(screenshot):
[image]

You can review this approach in action in [this demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/DemoCenter/Silverlight/?LayoutControlDemo#Module=DataLayoutControl?Product=DXLayoutControl.SL) (the link points to the Silverlight version, but the WPF version behaves exactly the same). You can either use the attributes from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace or use the Fluent-API to manage the process of property-editors generation.

**Update:**
You can use the [DataLayoutControl.AutoGeneratingItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfLayoutControlDataLayoutControl_AutoGeneratingItemtopic) event to change the editor for any property. This approach is already discussed in the following DevExpress Support threads:
   - [How to Customize controls inside WPF DataLayoutControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q414161)
   - [WPF DataLayoutControl questions](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q459834)
   - [DataLayoutControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T105768)

P.S. In the future, I suggest you use [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) to get official and guaranteed assistance on the use of DevExpress products.

Comment: and how can I bind/render a DataLayoutControl class from my viewmodel, in the mvvm design pattern?

Comment: A bit strange question to me ...Just add the DataLayoutControl into  View, and then bind the DataLayoutControl.CurrentItem property to the SelectedItem property of your ViewModel.

Comment: maybe a silly question? =) sorry, I'm at the start of my mvvm experience! :) thank you! :)

Comment: I have edited the question, I'm trying to do like you said me, but it still doesn't work

Comment: it works if I bind it to my gridcontrol.. now is better, but it still shows: 1) field I don't want to see; 2) errors in foreign keys

Comment: How do I bind the class defining my layout to my datalayoutcontrol?

Comment: and if I have a boolean value in my model to map into a yes/no  input?

Comment: Boolean value will be mapped into CheckEdit. Please, see the demo and documentation links, i've referred in my answer which demonstrates most aspects of mapping.

Comment: And you can use the [DataLayoutControl.AutoGeneratingItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfLayoutControlDataLayoutControl_AutoGeneratingItemtopic) event for tuning of generated items.

Comment: yes, but I don't want the checkEdit, I want customize it.. and also for the value from a foreign table..

Comment: Updated my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the gridview of `FocusedRowChanged` event.

```
propertyGridControl1.SelectedObject = gridView1.GetFocusedRow();
```